# external script loaded dynamically is not evaluated

Tags: javascript, jquery

A third party has an external script to display a streaming web cam into an existing div.  There are multiple web cams available, so I want to fire the script after the user has selected a web cam to view.

The vendor's embedding code includes a div in which the video stream will be displayed and a script tag which calls a javascript file.

```
<div id="player_cam1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="[url for cam1 external .js]"></script>
```

when the same script tag is embedded in a static page, the script places a flash object in the player div.

If I use jquery to add the script tag to the page after the user clicks on a link to select a camera, I can see in fiddler that the javascript file is loaded with a status of 200 and the response returned is the same as that when the script tag is in the page source before it loads. The return is

eval(function(){...})

When the tag is added via jQuery, however, the flash player is not embedded within the div.

There are no errors in the javascript console.

The same thing happens if I use

```
jQuery.getScript([url for cam1 external .js]);
```

In sum, script tag present when page loads-- all works fine,  script tag added after page loads, flash player is not embedded.

As a test I copied the the js returned by the script tag to a local file with alerts on either side of the function.  When that tag is present when the page loads, the flash player embeds correctly.  When it is added dynamically, the alerts pop up but the flash player is not embedded. again, no errors in the javascript console.

Comment: My guess is it IS evaluating the script; the script just isn't doing what you expect it to.

Comment: Open your JS console (F12 on windows), it will tell you what's wrong. If you can't figure it out, edit your question and add these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your script may be violating the [Javascript Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).  In that case, it would rightfully not evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Doh! The script called by the external js creates a second script which adds an event to onLoad.  It's that event which calls a function to load the player.